# SQL FIFO inventory query for aging a dynamic number of units

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sum, window-functions

I have the below table of inventory transactions that I would like to use to identify the age of units I sell.

I would like a script that will allow me to input a number of units to buy, and the result spit out which units will be selected based on FIFO logic.

The **type** identifies if a transaction is an IN vs OUT.

**Example:** A customer would like to buy 50 units on Jan 31.

My table has the following transactions before Jan 31.

```
id   date    units  type 
1    Jan 1   10     1
2    Jan 10  45     1
3    Jan 12  -15    -1
4    Jan 25  20     1
```

**Step 1:** Apply FIFO using a SQL window function

```
drop table if exists ##transactions
go

select *
into ##transactions
FROM (
    select 1 id, '1/1/2020' date, 10 units, 1 type UNION ALL
    select 2 id, '1/10/2020' date, 45 units, 1 type UNION ALL
    select 3 id, '1/12/2020' date, -15 units, -1 type UNION ALL
    select 4 id, '1/25/2020' date, 20 units, 1 type
) a

SELECT id, date, units, IIF(cumulative > 0, cumulative, 0) cumulative FROM (
    SELECT id, date, units, SUM(units) OVER (ORDER BY type, date) AS cumulative FROM ##transactions
) a
ORDER BY date
```

**Results:**

```
id   date   units  cumulative
1    Jan 1  10     0
2    Jan 10 45     40
3    Jan 12 -15    0
4    Jan 25 20     60
```

**Step 2:** Pick X number of units (where X = 50)

`code help please`

**Results** (Desired):

```
id   date   units  cumulative  selected
1    Jan 1  10     0           0
2    Jan 10 45     40          40
3    Jan 12 -15    0           0
4    Jan 25 20     60          10
```

This will tell me that 40 units from my Jan 10 inventory and 10 units from my Jan 25 inventory will be picked.

I would like the procedure to work in a way that I can input any number, and the result set will return the correct available values based on FIFO.

Comment: I don't understand the logic you expect for the window sum - and I can't see how the query in step 1 would generate the result you are showing.

Comment: @GMB I've updated the query to show the exact results. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @amount_to_deduct int = 50

SELECT *, 
case when cumulative = 0 or units < 0 then 0
     when cumulative < @amount_to_deduct and cumulative < units then cumulative
     when cumulative < @amount_to_deduct and cumulative >= units then units
     when cumulative - units < @amount_to_deduct and cumulative < units then @amount_to_deduct
     when cumulative - units < @amount_to_deduct and cumulative >= units then @amount_to_deduct - cumulative + units
     else 0
     end as selected
FROM (
  SELECT id, date, units, IIF(cumulative > 0, cumulative, 0) cumulative
  FROM (
      SELECT id, date, units, SUM(units) OVER (ORDER BY type, date) AS cumulative FROM transactions
  ) a
) b
ORDER BY date
```

Here's a sql fiddle with some extra testing data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b0584/10

I tested with cases of 50, 30, 100, and 150 using that sample and the data looked to be correct

Comment: Thank you, I believe this catches all scenarios. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a window sum of `cumulative` and conditional logic:

```
select id, date, units,
    case 
        when sum(cumulative) over(order by date) < 50
            then cumulative
        when sum(cumulative) over(order by date) - cumulative < 50
            then 50 - sum(cumulative) over(order by date) + cumulative
        else 0
    end as selected
from (
    select id, date, units, 
        case when sum(units) over (order by type, date) > 0
            then sum(units) over (order by type, date)
            else 0
        end as cumulative 
    from ##transactions
) a
order by date
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ad39b5291fb5d22a58f291afba2b9c69)** - I added another row at the end of the table to demonstrates what happens to the "next" inventory line once the target quantity is reached:

```
id | date      | units | selected
-: | :-------- | ----: | -------:
 1 | 1/1/2020  |    10 |        0
 2 | 1/10/2020 |    45 |       40
 3 | 1/12/2020 |   -15 |        0
 4 | 1/25/2020 |    20 |       10
 4 | 1/26/2020 |    30 |        0
```

Comment: Very close, but please see this fiddle: 

[FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8e47006bac02a5f0fe22f40aaa91511e)

Comment: @warrenk: what is the problem?

Comment: The date format was wrong in my fiddle, it has been updated now: [FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e6d9c28713b5af0a55f9ed9aca39423a)


You may see the issue now on line id = 4. The number of units is 16, but the selected units are 22. I can't sell more units than I have.